# The FFmpeg just show the number form the input text (no characters , just numbers) error=13, Permission denied

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I was trying to use FFmpeg to create a video form gif and audio, on Android 10, doesn't work
The code is working fine on android 9 and below, and not work 10 and above
the Cmd, as I mentioned it is work so good on android 9 and below

```
 String[] cmd = new String[24];
    cmd[0] = "-i";
    cmd[1] = audio.getPath();
    cmd[2] = "-ignore_loop";
    cmd[3] = "0";
    cmd[4] = "-i";
    cmd[5] = image_path;
    cmd[6] = "-vf";
    cmd[7] = "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2";
    cmd[8] = "-filter:v";
    cmd[9] = ayat_drawer + qara_draw;
    cmd[10] = "-vcodec";
    cmd[11] = "libx264";
    cmd[12] = "-pix_fmt";
    cmd[13] = "yuv420p";
    cmd[14] = "-r";
    cmd[15] = "25";
    cmd[16] = "-preset";
    cmd[17] = "ultrafast";
    cmd[18] = "-c:a";
    cmd[19] = "aac";
    cmd[20] = "-b:a";
    cmd[21] = "128k";
    cmd[22] = "-shortest";
    cmd[23] = outputLocation.getPath();
```

**The Java code :**

```
 FFmpeg mFFmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context);
        try {
            mFFmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(String message) {
                    super.onProgress(message);
                    callback.onProgress(message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String message) {
                    super.onSuccess(message);
                    Utils.refreshGallery(outputLocation.getPath(), context);
                    callback.onSuccess(outputLocation, "video");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(String message) {
                    super.onFailure(message);
                    if (outputLocation.exists()) {
                        outputLocation.delete();
                    }
                    callback.onFailure(new IOException(message));
                }

                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    Log.d("TAG", "<ffmpeg>Started command : mFFmpeg " + java.util.Arrays.toString(cmd));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Log.d("TAG", "<ffmpeg>Finished command : mFFmpeg " + java.util.Arrays.toString(cmd));
                    super.onFinish();
                    callback.onFinish();
                }
            });
        } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
            Log.e("MAS" , e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I think that because FFmpeg using Asynctask and it is deprecated

Comment: Can you please put the log that shows error??

Comment: To fix this problem , see : https://github.com/umeshlakhani7170/ffmpeg-video-editor-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was found a solution by using this code :
https://github.com/umeshlakhani7170/ffmpeg-video-editor-android